# Python pathlib - is this a correct way to join paths in a platform independent way?

Tags: python-3.x, path

I have started converting code which I want run on both posix and windows from `os.path` to the `pathlib.Path` module. Specifically, I replaced -

```
import os
os.path.join('grandparent_dir', 'parent_dir', 'file_name')
```

with

```
from pathlib import Path
Path('grandparent_dir', 'parent_dir', 'file_name')
```

It seems to work but I can't find this way of instantiating the class in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Is it good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation on Pure Paths](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths),  I have just found an example instantiation -

```
PurePath('foo', 'some/path', 'bar')
```

Since `pathlib.Path` is a [subclass of `PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#concrete-paths), it must also be valid `pathlib.Path`